# How to avoid multiple variable re-declarations on function outputs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following example

```
function doSomethingToAVariable(variable){
    return variable + 1
}

function doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime(variable){
    return variable + 2
}

function doSomethingToAVariableLastly(variable){
    return variable + 3
}

var myVariable = 0;
myVariable = doSomethingToAVariable(myVariable);
myVariable = doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime(myVariable);
myVariable = doSomethingToAVariableLastly(myVariable);

console.log(myVariable); // 6
```

How do I avoid the nasty myVariable re-declarations? Could wrapping each of the functions into a Promise chain be a solution?

Comment: There's no redeclaration here, you're just reusing the variable, which is fine. If it really bothers you, you can wrap function calls inside each other. Also, promises aren't meant for this, they're for async function calls that you want to follow up on.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Why is there a node.js tag used here?

Comment: I think this is really good question. Have your tried looking a functional composition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function composition to the rescue. 
Take a look at libraries for functional programming, like Ramda, or lodash-fp.

here a plain JS snippet to compose functions:

```
//the compose-method you find in your regular FP-libs
var compose = (...funcs) => (value) => funcs.reduceRight((v,fn)=>fn(v), value);
//or a function wich takes the functions in opposite order, 
//wich might be more common to you
var pipe = (...funcs) => (value) => funcs.reduce((v,fn)=>fn(v), value);
```

compose is a direct mapping of the composition you try to build

```
var composition = (value) => a(b(c(value)));
var composition = compose(a, b, c);
//it calls the functions from right to left
```

pipe is more oriented on your known imperative style to process a value step by step

```
var composition = function(value){
    value = c(value);
    value = b(value);
    value = a(value);
    return value;
}
//pipe the value through c, then through b, then through a
var fn = pipe(c, b, a);
//wich in the end does exactly the same as the code built by compose
```

so back to your code:

```
var composition = pipe(
    doSomethingToAVariable,
    doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime,
    doSomethingToAVariableLastly
);
//or
var composition = compose(
    doSomethingToAVariableLastly,
    doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime,
    doSomethingToAVariable
);

//and run it
var myVariable = composition(0);
```

Comment: Warning, not all browsers support arrow functions yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to chain then you need to return the object instead which will contain the final value

```
function variableOperations( initialValue )
{
  this.value = initialValue;
  this.someOp1 = function(){ this.value += 1; return this; } 
  this.someOp2 = function(){ this.value += 2; return this; } 
}

var a = new variableOperations(1); //new object
a.someOp1().someOp2();

alert(a.value); //alerts 4
```

Comment: urgh, that's OK for jQuery, but IMHO it's a bit heavy for something working on plain data types

Comment: Why are you talking about jQuery ?

Comment: @Roque because this is the design pattern used by jQuery, one of the most well-known JS libraries

Comment: @Alnitak It is true, just giving an example of how chaining is done. I don't think  OP's usecase is what he has shown example of.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're looking for what's called "function composition":

```
var myVariable = doSomethingToAVariableLastly(doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime(doSomethingToAVariable(0)));
```

but this is clearly not readable with such long function names.

Promises are typically only useful for asynchronous operations, and whilst they'd work in this scenario, the result would be inefficient and would introduce async dependencies where none are needed:

```
var promise = doSomethingToAVariable(0);
        .then(doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime);
        .then(doSomethingToAVariableLastly);
```

since you can only access the final result from the end of the chain of `.then` callbacks:

```
promise.then(function(myVariable) {
    // myVariable is now 6, and in scope
}

// but it's not in scope or usable here
```

Comment: Are there any other design patterns that could help?

Comment: Promises are not necessarily async. There is way to do this with promise without any async.

Comment: @Roque do tell?  AFAIK, most Promise APIs explicitly use asynchronous dispatch of their callbacks.

Comment: If you synchronously call `resolve` in the promise's body, the promise is synchronously resolved. That is for its standard implementation at least.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at a functional approach with Ramda?

```
R.compose(
  doSomethingToAVariableLastly,
  doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime,  
  doSomethingToAVariable
)(myVariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, your code is perfectly fine.

But, you can do something like this if you really want to "chain" the calls. It is a bit less efficient though.

```js
function chainCalls(initVal, funcs){
  return funcs.reduce(function(val, f){
    return f(val);
  }, initVal || 0);
}

function doSomethingToAVariable(variable){
    return variable + 1
}

function doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime(variable){
    return variable + 2
}

function doSomethingToAVariableLastly(variable){
    return variable + 3
}

var myVariable = chainCalls(0, [doSomethingToAVariable,
                                doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime,
                                doSomethingToAVariableLastly]);

document.write(myVariable);
```

Another alternative is to create a reusable function chain like this.

```js
function functionChain(){
  var funcs = arguments;
  return function(value){
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(funcs, function(value, f){
      return f(value);
    }, value);
  };
}

function doSomethingToAVariable(variable){
    return variable + 1
}

function doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime(variable){
    return variable + 2
}

function doSomethingToAVariableLastly(variable){
    return variable + 3
}

var myVariable = functionChain(
  doSomethingToAVariable,
  doSomethingToAVariableASecondTime,
  doSomethingToAVariableLastly
)(0);

document.write(myVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's as simple as adding some things together how about a recursive method. A bit like using promises but without actually using them.

```
function add(x) {
  return {
    done: () => x,
    add: (y) => add(x + y)
  }
}

let myVariable = 0;
add(myVariable).add(1).add(2).add(3).done(); // 6
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kv7wff9e/1/)