# How to write a middleware class in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, middleware

I have researched the topic for hours on Google and books and I could only find very specific implementations. I'm struggling to write a simple Middleware class in node JS with only plain vanilla javascript (no additional module like async, co,..). My goal is to understand how it works not to get the most optimised code.

I would like something as simple as having a string and adding new string to it thru the use of middleware.

The class

```
"use strict";
class Middleware {
    constructor() {
        this.middlewares = [];
    }
    use(fn) {
        this.middlewares.push(fn);
    }
    executeMiddleware(middlewares, msg, next) {
       // This is where I'm struggling
    }
    run(message) {
        this.executeMiddleware(this.middlewares, message, function(msg, next) {
            console.log('the initial message : '+ message);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Middleware;
```

A possible usage

```
const Middleware = require('./Middleware');
const middleware = new Middleware();

middleware.use(function(msg, next) {
    msg += ' World';
    next();
});

middleware.use(function(msg, next) {
    msg += ' !!!';
    console.log('final message : ' + msg);
    next();
});
middleware.run('Hello');
```

As a result the msg variable will end up being : 'Hello World !!!'

Comment: what exactly do you struggle with? And (why) do you need this class?

Comment: What you show seems to me like basic [function composition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37027673/6567275).

Comment: You need to describe better what your end goal is.  Middleware is usually used in conjunction with processing of some object or request where there's a standard interface that allows lots of different code to "plugin" to the processing of that specific object or request, yet you don't describe any such thing.  As it is, we don't really know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @thomas @jfriend00 for educational purpose I made the example super simple but it is actually part of a bigger class. I need this middleware pattern in order to augment a JS object based on user input information and also to collect some data in order to save it in a DB.
**What i'm actually struggling with** is the logic inside of the _executeMiddleware_ method. I have tried to loop thru the array of middlewares and call each function `middleware.call(this, arg, next)` problem is, the data don't persist between middlewares.  The last middleware receive 'Hello' and not 'Hello World'.

Comment: yes, because your functions don't propagate the changed `msg`. `msg` is just a local `var` that get's overwritten and after that you call a function `next()`. This ain't C pointer.

Comment: and this would be one way to build `executeMiddleware(middlewares, msg, next) { var composition = middlewares.reduceRight((next, fn) => v => { fn(v, next) }, next); composition(msg); }`. This implementation doesn't prevent a function to call `next()` multiple times. On the other hand, it's pretty much what `run(msg)` attempts to do, and can be cached and reused, till `middlewares` changes.

Comment: @Thomas I have implemented the executeMiddleware method as you suggested but the final middleware receives an undefined message.
Trace :`final message : undefined !!!
the initial message : Hello`

Comment: what about the other comment? That your functions don't propagate the changes they make to `msg`; nor any other value. Through the lack of explicit values, they propagate an implicit `undefined` value, and that's what you see in your result.

Comment: @Thomas I saw that comment. and if I had a solution to that, I would have shared it here. but i'm still stuck with this issue.

Comment: @Thomas If you have the solution that would greatly helm me. I can't seem to get my head around this thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those looking for a working example.

```
// MIDDLEWARE CLASS
"use strict";
let info = { msg: '' };

class Middleware {
    constructor() {
        this.middlewares = [];
    }

    use(fn) {
        this.middlewares.push(fn);
    }

    executeMiddleware(middlewares, data, next) {
        const composition = middlewares.reduceRight((next, fn) => v => {
            // collect next data
            info = data;
            fn(info, next)
        }, next);       
        composition(data);
    }

    run(data) {
        this.executeMiddleware(this.middlewares, data, (info, next) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Middleware;
```

Usage example :

```
// index.js
const Middleware = require('./Middleware');
const middleware = new Middleware();

middleware.use(function(info, next) {
    info.msg += ' World';
    next();
});

middleware.use(function(info, next) {
    info.msg += ' !!!';
    next();
});

// Run the middleware with initial value
middleware.run({msg: 'Hello'});
```

Comment: how to return data?

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer has a few issues, namely unused/uneeded variables. Also id just like to post an alternative answer since thats what stackexchange is for.

*Usage example is the same*

```
class Middleware {
  constructor() {
    this.middlewares = [];
  }
  use(fn) {
     this.middlewares.push(fn);
  }
  executeMiddleware(data, done) {
    this.middlewares.reduceRight((done, next) => () => next(data, done), done)
(data);
  }
  run(data) {
    this.executeMiddleware(data, done => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: What about a usage example for a single api resource/endpoint?  For example, if I have 5 resources in an api 'controller', and I only want to apply certain middleware logic to 2 of the 5 resources.  With function-based middleware, I'd use something like:

```app.post('/item', middlewareOnlyForThisResource, (req, res, next) => ...```

Answer (score 0):

```
class InputValidation {

    constructor() {

    }
    getData(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req)
//your stuff here
        next();
    }
}

module.exports = new InputValidation();

//Just import into main module and make a middleware



  const InputValidation = require("./validation/inputValidation");
    app.use(InputValidation.getData);
```